# Foundation: _userInfoForFileAndLine (Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException) in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, appdelegate, ios15

I'm getting error report from Crashlytics.

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.

Is there anyone know this issue about ?

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x91cac __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x14758 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x12361c _userInfoForFileAndLine. BOLD HERE
3  UIKitCore                      0x18dca0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _setHostsLayoutEngine:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1eb68 -[UITableViewCellContentView _tableViewCellContentViewCommonSetup]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1eb20 -[UITableViewCellContentView initWithCoder:]
6  UIFoundation                   0x60644 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
7  UIFoundation                   0x60870 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
8  UIFoundation                   0x35dc -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x43b1d4 -[UIView initWithCoder:]
10 UIKitCore                      0xd4744 -[UITableViewCell initWithCoder:]
11 KiniGajian                     0x34c34 (Missing UUID e1ba06bc200b37459b52e856214bf0ee)
12 UIKitCore                      0x3f5548 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]
13 UIFoundation                   0x60644 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
14 UIFoundation                   0x35dc -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
15 UIKitCore                      0x5676f0 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
16 UIFoundation                   0x60644 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
17 UIFoundation                   0x60870 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
18 UIFoundation                   0x35dc -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x569e44 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:]
20 UIKitCore                      0x50c8c0 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x2858e8 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:]
22 UIKitCore                      0x1cda60 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]
23 UIKit                          0x8c66c -[UITableViewAccessibility dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]
24 UIKitCore                      0x553ae0 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:]
25 UIKitCore                      0x1ed1d8 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
26 UIKit                          0x8c788 -[UITableViewAccessibility dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
27 KiniGajian                     0x26f80 (Missing UUID e1ba06bc200b37459b52e856214bf0ee)
28 KiniGajian                     0x27220 (Missing UUID e1ba06bc200b37459b52e856214bf0ee)
29 UIKitCore                      0x2727e0 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
30 UIKitCore                      0x461130 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsForRanges:createIfNecessary:]
31 UIKitCore                      0x297c8c -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
32 UIKitCore                      0x16dc00 -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
33 UIKitCore                      0x17db28 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
34 QuartzCore                     0x3cc4c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
35 QuartzCore                     0x2fd40 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
36 QuartzCore                     0x434a4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
37 QuartzCore                     0x4c08c CA::Transaction::commit()
38 QuartzCore                     0x2f4b0 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool)
39 CoreFoundation                 0x3df34 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
40 CoreFoundation                 0xf578 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
41 CoreFoundation                 0xab0c __CFRunLoopRun
42 CoreFoundation                 0x1dd8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific
43 GraphicsServices               0x19a0 GSEventRunModal
44 UIKitCore                      0x4edfa8 -[UIApplication _run]
45 UIKitCore                      0x28222c UIApplicationMain
46 APPS                       0x7470 main + 19 (AppDelegate.swift:19)
47 ???                            0x103340190 (Missing)
```

I'm not creating any tableview from the recent update.
If i check AppDelegate line 19. It shows import UserNotifications. Is there any problem on it because it's **do not embed** in general setting ? Or any other issue there?

Comment: Is your app KiniGajian? If so, it seems you have problems with dSYM in Crashlytics, because it shows "Missing UUID". If it's your app, then these lines should be the most interesting and you should want to decipher them first.

Comment: it's one of the module in my apps. What's the meaning if missing UUID? Because when i open the module there is no error either XCODE or inside IOS apps. I don't get any crash   @lazarevzubov

Comment: In order to let Crashlytics "decipher" your crash logs, you need to upload dSYM files of your app there. See, for example, official docs how to do it automatically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading It doesn't always work as you expect, so see also posts like this for detailed instructions: https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-fix-the-missing-dsyms-on-firebase-crashlytics-5f36d9db51d9 If you do everything correctly, you should see your classes and methods in crash logs instead of Missing UUID.